# Which kanban software integrates with TFS?

Tags: tfs, kanban

I am doing research for Kanban tools which has the ability to download Work items from TFS, what i have found so far are [Eylean board](http://www.eylean.com) and [UrbanTurtle](http://www.urbanturtle.com). If you could post others, I would really appreciate this, but the requirements is a solid supported tools, not open source rarely updated projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What functionality are you looking for exactly? TFS 2013 (and TFS Online) have a Kanban board

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj838789.aspx

There is some support in TFS 2012 (Post Update 1), but not sure how much they have.

Comment: The integrated Kanban board only allow to group by backlog or people, cons for me

Comment: @allenhwkim hey, not sure what you mean, could you explain or make a picture? I've found the TFS board to be very flexible and the latest updates in 2015 / online version have really made it nice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SwiftKanban from Digite integrates with TFS.  You can check it out at http://www.swiftkanban.com. It supports not only TFS but a large number of other software engineering and related tools.  All the best!

Answer (score 2):

LeanKit is a solid Kanban tool, arguably one of the leaders in Kanban tools along with Swift Digite. LeanKit does have functionality that allows it to integrate with TFS.

http://www.leankit.com

From Telerik, TeamPulse has an excellent TFS integration story and has some Kanban features, most notably the WIP limits on columns. It is more of a Scrumban implementation but it could meet your needs.

http://www.telerik.com/agile-project-management-tools/

Cheers.